# Pandas: how to adapt one dataframe to another based on the date?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, stock, mismatch

I have two data frames that collect historical price series of two different stocks. applying describe () I noticed that the elements of the first stock are 1291 while those of the second are 1275. This difference is due to the fact that the two securities are listed on different stock exchanges and therefore show differences on some dates. What I would like to do is keep the two separate dataframes, but make sure that in the first dataframe, all those rows whose dates are not present in the second dataframe are deleted in order to have the perfect matching of the two dataframes to do the analyzes. I have read that there are functions such as merge () or join () but I have not been able to understand well how to use them (if these are the correct functions). I thank those who will use some of their time to answer my question.

```
"ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 1, the array at index 0 has size 1275 and the array at index 1 has size 1291"
```

Thank you

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas_datareader as web
from scipy import stats
import seaborn as sns
pd.options.display.min_rows= None
pd.options.display.max_rows= None

tickers = ['DISW.MI','IXJ','NRJ.PA','SGOL','VDC','VGT']
wts= [0.19,0.18,0.2,0.08,0.09,0.26]

price_data = web.get_data_yahoo(tickers,
                               start = '2016-01-01',
                               end = '2021-01-01')
price_data = price_data['Adj Close']

ret_data = price_data.pct_change()[1:]
port_ret = (ret_data * wts).sum(axis = 1)

benchmark_price = web.get_data_yahoo('ACWE.PA',
                               start = '2016-01-01',
                               end = '2021-01-01')
                               
benchmark_ret = benchmark_price["Adj Close"].pct_change()[1:].dropna()

#From now i get error

sns.regplot(benchmark_ret.values,
port_ret.values)
plt.xlabel("Benchmark Returns")
plt.ylabel("Portfolio Returns")
plt.title("Portfolio Returns vs Benchmark Returns")
plt.show()

(beta, alpha) = stats.linregress(benchmark_ret.values,
                port_ret.values)[0:2]
                
print("The portfolio beta is", round(beta, 4))
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider a toy example.

df1 consists of 6 days of data and df2 consists of 5 days of data.

What I have understood, you want df1 also to have 5 days of data matching the dates with df2.

**df1**

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'date':pd.date_range('2021-05-17', periods=6),
    'px':np.random.rand(6)
})
df1
    date        px
0   2021-05-17  0.054907
1   2021-05-18  0.192294
2   2021-05-19  0.214051
3   2021-05-20  0.623223
4   2021-05-21  0.004627
5   2021-05-22  0.127086
```

**df2**

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'date':pd.date_range('2021-05-17', periods=5),
    'px':np.random.rand(5)
})
df2
    date        px
0   2021-05-17  0.650976
1   2021-05-18  0.393061
2   2021-05-19  0.985700
3   2021-05-20  0.879786
4   2021-05-21  0.463206
```

**Code**
To consider only matching dates in df1 from df2.

```
df1 = df1[df1.date.isin(df2.date)]
```

**Output df1**

```
    date        px
0   2021-05-17  0.054907
1   2021-05-18  0.192294
2   2021-05-19  0.214051
3   2021-05-20  0.623223
4   2021-05-21  0.004627
```

Comment: really many thanks for your reply. Does this function remove only the extremes or does a match between the dates? Because it could be that the dates that don't match are in the middle of the series.

Comment: It matches the dates from from all rows, you are getting the error because your df the column name might not be `date` but something else.